# How to slow down a rotate animation gradually

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-rotation

I am developing a roulette wheel app. In which if i tap on center button wheel should rotate for few seconds and then its speed should get slow down gradually. Please guide me in right way if anyone knows.

I could able to rotate an `imageView` with some uniform speed but i am facing struggle to slow down the wheel's speed gradually.

**Rotation code**

> ```
> CALayer *layer = container.layer;
> CAKeyframeAnimation *animation;
> animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
> animation.duration = 1.5f;
> animation.cumulative = YES;
> animation.repeatCount = 1;
> animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:       // i.e., Rotation values for the 3 keyframes, in RADIANS
>                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0 * M_PI],
>                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75 * M_PI],
>                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.5 * M_PI], nil];
> animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:     // Relative timing values for the 3 keyframes
>                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
>                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:.5],
>                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
> animation.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                              [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn], // from keyframe 1 to keyframe 2
>                              [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut], nil];  // from keyframe 2 to keyframe 3
> animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
> animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
> [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docs for CAKeyframeAnimation, you have the timingFunctions property to add easing etc

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any sample code to apply timingFunctions